# Saving raster using writeRaster in R

Tags: raster, r, nodata, stretch

I'm running some analysis in RStudio using raster and rgdal package.
Where I assign variable to some raster, or stack for example:

```
analysis = raster("M-34-91-B-a-1-4-4.img")
```

Then I run some analysis on this variable (classification, some function for every pixel), and I'm trying to save it using writeRaster function:

```
writeRaster(analysis, "analysis.tif")
```

My tif file is really small (53 KB) and when I'm trying to open it all I get is blank square with some black dots all around)

[image: Image after using writeRaster] <--- image

However, when I use plot function

```
plot(analysis, main = "Max height")
```

Everything in R works fine, and I'm able to export this plot using RStudio interface and resulting image is all fine (and weights more ~ 1 173 KB) (image below)

[image]

I tried reinstalling both R and RStudio, installing different file viewers like IrfanView etc. When I try to open written raster in ArcGIS Pro it works rather fine (image below)

[image]

I just noticed that black pixels from first image, are probably no data pixels after adding it to ArcGIS Pro.

Is it possible then that no data values (probably -9999) messed up the stretch in writeRaster function?

Comment: Are you trying to view a single-layer raster as if it was a full-colour image?

Comment: Well, you are right that single-layer won't give me a RGB image, but I think after using writeRaster function and opening it in any image editor capable of opening .tif extension I should get panchromatic raster like after loading it to ArcPro instead of full white image with just a few black dots.

Comment: Monochromatic maybe. Try writing a raster without missing values. If you make `r = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))` and write that does it look okay, then set `r[3,3]=NA` and write that and see what happens. Its likely the stretch. Your viewer isn't interpreting the missing value code. That's probably a GeoTIFF extension...

Comment: Okay, so I tried to do as You asked. And before assigning  `r[3,3] = NA` written raster was all blank, after adding this NoData pixel, the pixel on written Raster was  black. I'm pretty sure it is a problem with stretch because when I tried to download some GeoTIFF extension from web (Switzerland DEM for example) in my image viewer it looked "dimished", without good contrast. But after I added stretch to it in ArcGIS Pro it looked okay, hovewer when I removed stretch in ArcGIS Pro it looked the same as in image viewer. So the question is: Is it problem with R or my image viewer?

Comment: My main problem is that I have to send this raster file to my lecturer to pass the exercise, and in the script it is said to do it using writeRaster function. So I'm curious if I'm totally missing the point but I believe it should look monochromatic with white to black scale just as You said in  the comment before.